# Rails nested form error_messages not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

The whole code is from this question: [Nested form validations not working in rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041011/nested-form-validations-not-working-in-rails-app/12041191#12041191)

The validation works, but now the problem is with error_message. It is simply not showing up.

I found out that it won't work because of redirect_to in my controller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @trip = Trip.find(params[:trip_id])
    @message = @trip.messages.create(params[:message])     
  if @trip.messages.create
    MessageMailer.send_message(@message).deliver
    redirect_to thank_you_path        
  else    
    redirect_to trip_path(@trip)
  end
 end
end
```

And I have to use render instead. But the question is how?

This message form is inside another models show page and if the message doesn't pass validations, I want to see the error message in the same show page.

Can You help ? 
Thanks!

**Update:**

rake routes

```
     messages GET    /messages(.:format)                         {:action=>"
 index", :controller=>"messages"}
             POST   /messages(.:format)                         {:action=>"
 create", :controller=>"messages"}
  new_message GET    /messages/new(.:format)                     {:action=>"
 new", :controller=>"messages"}
  edit_message GET    /messages/:id/edit(.:format)                {:action=>"
 edit", :controller=>"messages"}
     message GET    /messages/:id(.:format)                     {:action=>"
 show", :controller=>"messages"}
              PUT    /messages/:id(.:format)                     {:action=>"
 update", :controller=>"messages"}
              DELETE /messages/:id(.:format)                     {:action=>"
 destroy", :controller=>"messages"}
 trip_messages GET    /trips/:trip_id/messages(.:format)          {:action=>"
 index", :controller=>"messages"}
              POST   /trips/:trip_id/messages(.:format)          {:action=>"
 create", :controller=>"messages"}
 new_trip_message GET    /trips/:trip_id/messages/new(.:format)      {:action=>"
 new", :controller=>"messages"}
 edit_trip_message GET    /trips/:trip_id/messages/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"
 edit", :controller=>"messages"}
 trip_message GET    /trips/:trip_id/messages/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"
 show", :controller=>"messages"}
              PUT    /trips/:trip_id/messages/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"
 update", :controller=>"messages"}
              DELETE /trips/:trip_id/messages/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"
 destroy", :controller=>"messages"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

     def create
         @trip = Trip.find(params[:trip_id])
         @message = @trip.messages.build(params[:message])     
         if @message.save
              MessageMailer.send_message(@message).deliver
              redirect_to thank_you_path        
         else    
              render "edit"
         end
     end
end
```

Then you should have a partial called `_edit.html.erb` within `views/messages` that contains your form and your code to render the errors.

And your `edit.html.erb` can just be something like `render "edit"`

---

Quick comment:

you should change this:

```
form_for([@trip, @trip.messages.build])
```

to

```
form_for([@trip, @message])
```

And set `@message` (`@message = @message.new`) in the `new` action. That way, you can use the same form for the new and edit action.

You could also think about using a gem like `simple_form` that makes creating forms a lot easier, and you would have errors displayed inline.

Comment: No, I don't have _edit partial. That's why **render** is tricky in my case.

Comment: I'm telling you to create it ;)

Comment: Ok :) I created it, and now I'm simply redirected to  `/trips/44/messages` edit form, but still no error messages.

Comment: In the _edit partial, at the top, write: `<%= @message.errors.full_messages.inspect %>`. You should be able to see if there are validations errors.

Comment: Sure, I edited my answer with an small comment that could help improve your code a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
render "/other_model/show"
```

Rendering preserves the current instance variables so if your "if" statement fails, the validations will load the `@trip` variable with the errors and that will be reflected in the newly rendered form.

Comment: I got  `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"locations"}`.

Comment: I can't understand why this controller locations. It has nothing to do with messages. It's a parent model for trips.

Comment: @emils I can't be sure without seeing your app, might be you're linking to it somewhere

Comment: You get this error because you're probably rendering the wrong partial (a partial that requires a @location variable to be set, or something like that)